# Hibernate execute only the first custom constraint for a java property

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, repository, constraints

I'm using Hibernate to create custom constraint annotations for my java model. Each constraint when invoked returns a specific API error message and 400 Bad Request as the HTTP status code.
Response from each constraint :-

```
{
"errorMsg": "revoked id",
"errorCode": 400
},

{
"errorMsg": "paused id",
"errorCode": 400
},

{
"errorMsg": "expired id",
"errorCode": 400
}
```

These are the custom constraints created `ExistingExpiredId`, `ExistingPausedId`, `ExistingRevokedId` :-

```
@NotBlank
@ExistingExpiredId
@ExistingPausedId
@ExistingRevokedId
private String id;
```

ID can have the following states :- `EXPIRED, PAUSED, REVOKED`. Currently I have custom annotations which checks for the different states of the property. Each custom constraint makes a repository call to the database to pick the particular state the property is in. I see that all the constraints are invoked and hence 3 calls to the database are being made which is quite expensive for a single property. How do I ensure that only one among the three constraint is invoked at a time and not all three? Does `hibernate` provide any mechanism to implement this?

Comment: Maybe you could look at using @ConstraintComposition(OR) in conjunction with @ReportAsSingleViolation in an attempt to reduce the overhead

Answer (score 0):

[`@GroupSequence`](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups) is the standard way of ordering validation constraints. The only caveat is, you would need to put each of the constraints in a separate group.

If I were you, I would create a single, parameterized constraint annotation (with a `Status[] value()` property) that checks for the existence of the object with the given `id` and `state`s, which you could then use as follows:

```
@ExistingId(State.EXPIRED) // check if an expired entity exists

@ExistingId(State.PAUSED) // check if a paused entity exists

@ExistingId({State.EXPIRED, State.PAUSED, State.REVOKED}) // check if an entity exists in any of the listed statuses
```

If you want, you can then alias some of the versions of the state configuration like so:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target(...)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ExistingId(Status.EXPIRED)
public @interface ExistingExpiredId {...}
```